# MySQL: fast selection N random rows from table where pair of columns (not a column) is unique

Tags: mysql, performance, select, random, sql-order-by

There is a table that contains such columns:

**id, person_id, pet_id, description**

There are some statements about this table:

1. id is a primary key, autoincrement
2. Each pair (person_id, pet_id) is unique
3. id, person_id, pet_id is integer and is NOT NULL
4. "holes" are possible (max pet_id doesn't tell us there are totally (max) number of columns with such person_id)
5. It is very possible there are much more different person_id in the table, that average number of pet_id for each person.

**The question is: How to select random N pet_id of the current person_id fast?**

Example of the table:

```
1.  1   1     cat
2.  1   2     dog
3.  2   40    horse
4.  2   35    dog
5.  3   46    duck
6.  2   39    duck
7.  1   3     duck
..................
100000  403  12  monkey
```

Example: I want to select two RANDOM rows for the person number two. One of possible random choices is the row #3. and the row #6.
The choices should be really "random" (should appear with the same probability).

How to do it using mysql query SELECT?

P.S. Of course I've read about selecting several random rows from the table, the basic problem with some tricky solutions. But, in my case there are two rows, not one.

I'm thinking of a faster method than

```
select id from tablename where person_id = 2 order by random()  limit 2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your strawman query is as good as you can do.  If you don't have a person with lots of pets (and you have an index on `person_id`), it should run quite fast.  If you do have such a person, then you're out of luck.  Forget selecting randomly, even to determine how many pets such a person has requires time O(# pets).

One possible other idea which probably won't work for you: If you don't care about the independence of your selections (i.e., you might get the same random response every time), then you can add a column which you populate with a random number when the row is inserted.  Add an index on `person_id,random_column` and select the first N rows ordered by that pair.  Slightly better is to add multiple random columns and select one to order by at random.  Unfortunately, this doesn't scale well and I don't think you'd be happy with the results.

Comment: Thank you. Nice ideas to think, to try and even to try to extend. I've read it twice.
Am I right? - the less this table is modified (let's say, once a week and by admin and never by users, they just use it), the more sense is to add columns random_column1, ..., random_column20 and make 20 indexes (person_id,random_column1),...,(person_id,random_column20)? So the behavior will look "really random" for humans and the performance should be fine if the table is not changed by users every second. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, here we are reducing the time of random() function execution in Database.

```
 $max_sql = "SELECT max(id) AS max_id  FROM " . $table;
  $max_row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($max_sql));
  $random_number = mt_rand(1, $max_row['max_id']);

  $random_sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $table . "
                 WHERE " . $column . " >= " . $random_number . " 
                 ORDER BY " . $column . " ASC
                 LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, as far as I see, this way the random rows are not going to get the equal distribution. Let's see, if there are gaps  for pet_id 1,2,3,1000,10001 for the person number two, then the pair (person_id, pet_id)==(2, 1000)  would be chosen 997 times more often than (2,2). Also, you have to iterate it n successful times (and check your $random number in not in the array of chosen random numbers and that breaks a bit the equal distribution for the query even more).